# Basic Algebra problem giving me problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the basic algebra problem: $3 \dfrac{1}{4} × x - 2 = 14$

I've gotten this far:

$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × x - 2 = 14$

$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × x = 16$

$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × 4 = 13$

$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × 4 \dfrac{37}{40} = 16.00625$

The problem is, I have the answer, which is 64/13, but I have absolutely no idea how to come about that number. Even odder is 64 / 13 = 4 23076448177/24999485525, so you could say I'm "stuck". Can somebody please explain to me how to get to the answer? Sorry if this is overly-basic, usually I can somehow figure this out, but it's giving me trouble.

**EDIT**: The reasoning for $3 \dfrac{1}{4} × 4 = 13$ is because I picked a random number for $x$, and if $x = 5$, the output is $16.25$, which is too large, and if I pick $4$ than the output is too small, so I know the answer lies somewhere between 4 and 5.

**EDIT 2**: Thank you all for your answers, all very helpful. I feel thoroughly stupid for not using the fundamental properties of algebra. My mistake. Again thanks for all your answers!

Comment: What did you do between $3\frac{1}{4} \cdot x = 16$ and $3\frac{1}{4} \cdot 4 = 13$?

Comment: @JiK I picked a random number for $x$ and continued to do that until I got $13$.

Comment: That's not the correct way to solve an equation @Jacedc, the point is to find $x$ through algebra, not trial and error. Check my answer below for the algebraic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have $3\tfrac{1}{4}\cdot x=16$, multiplying both sides by $4$ removes all the fractions and leaves an equation with only integers. Then dividing both sides by the appropriate integer yields the result.

Comment: Ahh, okay. That's right. I have no idea why I tried solving it through trial and error, my mistake. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7):

$$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × x - 2 = 14$$

Remember in algebra - what you do to one side, you must to do the other!

First, let's make the fraction into a more *usable* fraction. What's $3 \dfrac{1}{4}$? Well, we know that to have $1$ we would need $4 \times \frac{1}{4}$. Hence, to have 3, you would need 3 times that! That's $\frac{12}{4}$ for **3**. Keep in mind that we have 3 **AND** $\frac{1}{4}$, meaning that you'll have to add the $\frac{12}{4}$ to $\frac{1}{4}$. So the fraction ends up being: $\frac{13}{4}$.

$$\frac{13}{4} × x - 2 = 14$$

Now let's start using the fundamental rule of algebra that I mentioned earlier. Whatever you do to one side, you have to do to the other.

We first see the $-2$ next to the $x$ term. We don't want that. How do we eliminate? Add 2 to that side to make it zero:

$$\frac{13}{4} × x - 2 \color{red}{+2} = \frac{13}{4} × x \color{red}{+0}=\frac{13}{4} × x$$

Yay! Got rid of it! BUT WAIT! That's just the left side. What about the right side?

Must apply the same deal. Add 2 as well:

$$14 \color{red}{+2} =16$$

Therefore, we now have:

$$\frac{13}{4} × x=16$$

We want $x$ to be alone so we can get it's value. What else can we do to cancel? Hmm... OH! I GOT IT! Multiply by the **RECIPROCAL**.

The reciprocal of $\frac{13}{4}$ is, very simply, $\frac{4}{13}$. A reciprocal is basically taking a fraction and flipping it. The reciprocal times the original number will equal **1**. This is because the denominator will cancel the other numerator, and the numerator will cancel the other denominator.

Thus, we'll have to multiply the left side by the reciprocal:

$$\frac{13}{4} \color{red}{\times \frac{4}{13}} \times x=\color{red}{1}x=x$$

YES! We've got $x$ alone. Woohoo! Now just apply it to the right side:

$$16 \color{red}{\times \frac{4}{13}}=\frac{64}{13}$$

Combining it all~

$$x=\frac{64}{13}$$

YAY! DONE.

Cheers!
-Shahar

Answer (score 4):

We start with the initial equation:
$$(3+\frac 14)x-2=14$$

We simplify:
$$ \frac {13}4x-2 = 14 $$

We add 2 to both sides:
$$\frac {13}4x = 16$$

Then we multiply both sides by 4:
$$13x = 64$$

And then divide both sides by 13:
$$x = \frac{64}{13}$$

Your answer.

Comment: I think OP uses the notation $3\tfrac{1}{4}$ to mean $3+\tfrac{1}{4}$, or $\tfrac{13}{4}$.

Comment: I did, @Servaes is correct.

Comment: EDIT: Corrected the answer to reflect this.

Comment: It should be $(3+\frac{1}{4})\times x$, not $3+\frac{1}{4}\times x$.

Comment: You are correct. Editing again xD

Answer (score 1):

$$3 \dfrac{1}{4} × x - 2 = 14$$
$$\frac{13}{4} × x - 2 = 14$$
$$4\cdot\frac{13}{4} × x - 4\cdot2 =4\cdot 14$$
$$13 x - 8 =56$$
$$13x=56+8$$
$$13x=64$$
$$x=\frac{64}{13}$$
because
$$3 \dfrac{1}{4}=3+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{13}{4}$$

Comment: Correction, $14*4\neq64$ :)

Comment: You did $4⋅\dfrac{13}{4}x - 4⋅2 = 4⋅14$ thus multiplying both sides by 4 (which is correct) but you did it twice on the left side? ($4⋅2$)

Comment: it is my mistake